# RHEL NIC missing

Tags: linux, network-adapter, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have a RHEL server with 4 NICS. I bound eth2 and eth3 as `bond0`.

However, I don't know how to unbind the two NICs, so I just deleted `ifcfg-bond0`. Then I entered `service network restart`, and after that, I'm unable to find eth3. It's not loaded at all.

I've tried to reboot my server, but it's still not working...

Answer (score 1):

Remove `MASTER=bond0` from eth2/3 and also remove, also remove `alias bond0 bonding` from /etc/modprobe.conf

Answer (score 0):

In your **ifcfg-eth2** and **ifcfg-eth3** files under **/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts**, remove these two lines:

```
MASTER=bond0
SLAVE=yes
```

Restart your network service and everything should be ok.

Dont forget to clean up, remove any line having a **bond**-related configuration in your **/etc/modprobe.conf**